# cause of photoresist removal after etching

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-fabrication

I just tried to do a new PCB today with the photoresist method but what is very strange is that after etching it, I rinsed the board with water and wiped it dry, but as I wiped it dry with toilet paper, the photoresist came off and the underlying copper is exposed.

How is it possible for the photoresist to come off so easily like that?

Comment: May be the PCB material was not cleaned and processed as recommended when applying the resist. Did you buy PCB with applied photoresist or did you apply it yourself?

Comment: You obviously have a UV exposure problem.

Comment: Is the photoresist water-soluble?  In any case, once you have etched the board, you usually will want to remove the resist.

Comment: I bought the boards pre-coated with photoresist already on them from kinsten. And for UV exposure I used "insect killer" bulbs in a PCB exposure unit and exposed for 5 minutes.  I drill right after etch so I can see the holes better

Comment: https://kinsten.co/?group=eq

Comment: I wonder if Leon is right because I tried the same PCB 3x in an hour and attempt 3 is better and I started reading that fluorescent tubes take a while to turn on.